# jQuery Mousewheel loads every time and slows my website down

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website has become pretty slow lately.

Upon inspection of the Network tab, it seems that jQuery.mousewheel gets downloaded every single time.

It ends up looking something like this:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js?_=1515178223914
```

Every single time with a random number at the end.

Any way I can prevent this? Honestly I don't even know where this comes from.I am obviously using jQuery but it should stay in cache when downloaded once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would first try to locate the source of it and go from there. May be some tag piggyback it to be included on the site. Random number at the end prevents it being cached by the browser.

Comment: @Rikin The only references I get to the site is url="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"; as a variable to call this site, but this site seems to be generating the random numbers when loaded in Javascript. Anyway, I don't work on this project alone and I don't know if I can just delete it. Just making it downloading it once would be great.

Comment: its probably doing a redirect on `http://` request and thus generating a number at the end as instructed by redirect. Are you able to change it to `https://`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the jQuery part that loaded it (the else statement):

```
(function(init){
    var _rjs=typeof define==="function" && define.amd, /* RequireJS */
        _njs=typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports, /* NodeJS */
        _dlp=("https:"==document.location.protocol) ? "https:" : "http:", /* location protocol */
        _url="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js";
    if(!_rjs){
        if(_njs){
            require("jquery-mousewheel")($);
        }else{
            /* load jquery-mousewheel plugin (via CDN) if it's not present or not loaded via RequireJS
             (works when mCustomScrollbar fn is called on window load) */
      /*      $.event.special.mousewheel || $("head").append(decodeURI("%3Cscript src="+_dlp+"//"+_url+"%3E%3C/script%3E"));*/
        }
    }
    init();
}
```

For somewhat reasons it though it was never loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try download script and connect it to your project locally, without the numbers in the end. This numbers needs for you browser dont cache this script